# udev rules only running on first plug-in but not re-plug?

Tags: udev, usb-drive, nvme

I'm not sure why udev rules only trigger on first plug-in of a USB3 NVME enclosure but not any follow-up plugins. If i run `udevadm trigger` then the rules run again as expected. The goal of the rules is to enable UASP mode so that the device can be TRIMmed with `fstrim -av` discard commands.

Env: EndeavourOS/KDE
Device: Sabrent RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter

Here is my rule file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-uas-discard.rules`:

```
# Turn on "unmap" mode to allow "fstrim" et al. on USB-C/NVMe adaptors
# UGreen NVMe-to-USB-C adaptor
ACTION=="add|change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="174c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2362", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"
# ID 152d:0562 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. External
ACTION=="add|change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="152d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0562", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"
# ID 152d:0562 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. External
ACTION=="add|change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="152d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0583", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"
# Samsung T7 Touch 1TB SSD
ACTION=="add|change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4001", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"
# 0bda:9210 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter
ACTION=="add|change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9210", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"
```

Here is the sequence of me plugging it in from cold boot (rules run and discard info works), then unplugging it, then plugging it in again (discard info absent), then running `udevadm trigger` and finally `fstrim -av`.

any ideas why the rule does not trigger on follow-up re-plugs? the re-plug event log does look shorter than the initial one.

thanks!

```
// first login after cold boot
[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# lsblk -D
NAME        DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
nvme0n1            0      512B       2T         0
├─nvme0n1p1        0      512B       2T         0
└─nvme0n1p2        0      512B       2T         0

// plugging in RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter
[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[114.149081] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
KERNEL[114.149734] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[114.149755] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
UDEV  [114.162249] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
KERNEL[114.166748] add      /bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage (drivers)
KERNEL[114.166764] add      /module/usb_storage (module)
UDEV  [114.167535] add      /bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage (drivers)
UDEV  [114.167709] add      /module/usb_storage (module)
KERNEL[114.198213] add      /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_0 (workqueue)
KERNEL[114.198678] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0 (scsi)
KERNEL[114.198691] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[114.198706] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[114.198719] add      /bus/usb/drivers/uas (drivers)
KERNEL[114.198734] add      /module/uas (module)
UDEV  [114.198855] add      /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_0 (workqueue)
UDEV  [114.199318] add      /bus/usb/drivers/uas (drivers)
UDEV  [114.199859] add      /module/uas (module)
KERNEL[114.214531] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[114.214553] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[114.214566] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[114.214590] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[114.214601] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[114.240086] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [114.240689] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[114.305944] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[114.306061] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[114.364745] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [114.365141] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [114.367842] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
UDEV  [114.368427] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0 (scsi)
UDEV  [114.368994] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [114.369437] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [114.369892] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [114.370387] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [114.370897] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [114.371184] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [114.371196] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [114.580606] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [114.801345] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [114.802293] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[114.851725] add      /module/exfat (module)
UDEV  [114.852153] add      /module/exfat (module)
KERNEL[115.616240] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [115.785530] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
^C

[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# lsblk -D
NAME        DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda                0      512B       4G         0       <--- DISC-GRAN 512B
└─sda1             0      512B       4G         0       <--- DISC-GRAN 512B
nvme0n1            0      512B       2T         0
├─nvme0n1p1        0      512B       2T         0
└─nvme0n1p2        0      512B       2T         0

// unplugging RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter
[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[588.828217] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [589.386110] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[589.415468] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[589.415494] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[589.415505] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[589.415672] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[589.415719] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[589.415896] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [589.416517] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [589.417077] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [589.417282] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [589.417298] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [589.417456] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [589.418027] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[589.669806] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[589.669869] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[589.669930] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[589.670113] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[589.670149] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0 (scsi)
UDEV  [589.671366] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [589.671385] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [589.671727] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [589.672009] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [589.672278] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0 (scsi)
KERNEL[589.696497] remove   /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_0 (workqueue)
KERNEL[589.696756] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[589.696800] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [589.697326] remove   /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_0 (workqueue)
UDEV  [589.697749] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [589.698070] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[589.703445] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
KERNEL[589.703492] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
UDEV  [589.705078] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
UDEV  [589.705646] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
KERNEL[602.922604] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:37/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC (power_supply)
UDEV  [602.926982] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:37/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC (power_supply)
^C

[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# lsblk -D
NAME        DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
nvme0n1            0      512B       2T         0
├─nvme0n1p1        0      512B       2T         0
└─nvme0n1p2        0      512B       2T         0

// re-plugging RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter
[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[686.411970] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
KERNEL[686.413054] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[686.443125] add      /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_0 (workqueue)
KERNEL[686.443242] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]#1.0/host0 (scsi)
KERNEL[686.443251] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[686.443260] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[686.443271] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
UDEV  [686.444070] add      /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_0 (workqueue)
UDEV  [686.446323] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
UDEV  [686.447259] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [686.447828] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0 (scsi)
UDEV  [686.448445] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [686.448982] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [686.450968] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1 (usb)
KERNEL[686.459234] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[686.459266] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[686.459275] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[686.459360] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[686.459378] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [686.460296] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [686.460790] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [686.461314] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [686.461567] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [686.461987] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[686.484506] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [686.484960] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
KERNEL[686.548957] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[686.549011] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[686.631648] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [686.809723] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [687.031650] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [687.032506] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[687.810280] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [687.979196] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
^C

[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# lsblk -D
NAME        DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda                0        0B       4G         0       <--- DISC-GRAN 0B    ??
└─sda1             0        0B       4G         0       <--- DISC-GRAN 0B    ??
nvme0n1            0      512B       2T         0
├─nvme0n1p1        0      512B       2T         0
└─nvme0n1p2        0      512B       2T         0

[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# udevadm trigger         <--- re-trigger

[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# lsblk -D
NAME        DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda                0      512B       4G         0       <--- DISC-GRAN 512B
└─sda1             0      512B       4G         0       <--- DISC-GRAN 512B
nvme0n1            0      512B       2T         0
├─nvme0n1p1        0      512B       2T         0
└─nvme0n1p2        0      512B       2T         0

[root@endeavour-p14s leeoniya]# fstrim -av
/run/media/leeoniya/NVME: 893.7 GiB (959619530752 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda1
/boot/efi: 266.5 MiB (279408640 bytes) trimmed on /dev/nvme0n1p1
/: 908.5 GiB (975523504128 bytes) trimmed on /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

Comment: Just a guess but maybe `udev` caches the previous state and doesn't clear that saved state until `udevadm trigger` is executed. Maybe try adding some dumb rule such as `ACTION="remove" ... RUN+="/bin/true"` to make sure `udev` monitors the `remove` action, too?